# are there smarter ways to compse string for eval in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, eval

Say some looks like below

```
def fun s1,s2
  #code to process s1, s2
end

var1 = "value for s1"
var2 = "value for s2"
str_to_run = "fun '#{var1}', '#{var2}'"
eval str_to_run
```

My question is:  are there any other way to compose string for dynamically run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do use [`#public_send`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/public_send).

```
str_to_run = public_send "fun", var1, var2
```

Comment: thx for quick reply.  do you mean:  pulic_send "fund", 'var', 'var2'

Comment: I just try in irb,  I think "public_send "func", var1, var2" works,  'var1' will be passed as string "var1", not the string value.    Thank you for your suggestion.